# Difficulty assigning variables in python

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to write a very basic Python program to calculate the number of minutes per week.

I've created an `Hr_Per_Day` variable, but when I update this variable, `min_per_day`, which should update, doesn't. Why not?

Here's the code:

```py
Hr_Per_Day = 24
min_per_day = Hr_Per_Day * 60
min_per_day
**OUTPUT: 1440**
Hr_Per_Day = 26
min_per_day
**OUTPUT: 1440**
```

Why doesn't `min_per_day` update after I change `Hr_Per_Day` to 24? Any help would be appreciated!

I expected `min_per_day` to update after changing `Hr_Per_Day`.

Comment: Variables don't remember the expression that was used to assign them, they just get the result of the calculation. If you want to update the second variable, you have to assign it again.

Comment: This is true in almost all programming languages. Where did you learn that updating one variable would update the variable that depends on it?

Comment: @Barmar I've heard that if someone's only prior programming experience is with Excel formulas, they can think this way.

Comment: @JohnGordon Of course, I completely forgot about spreadsheets! I haven't used one in at least 20 years.

Comment: Thank you all! @JohnGordon, you're totally right: most of my prior programming experience is with Excel....

Answer (score 0):

```
min_per_day = Hr_Per_Day * 60
```

It seems like you expect this assignment to act like an *ongoing formula*, and if `Hr_Per_Day` ever changes, then `min_per_day` will also change.

Python doesn't work that way.

That assignment is a one-time calculation, using the value of `Hr_Per_Day`  *at that moment*.  If that value changes later, it will have no effect on `min_per_day`.